# If bot gets pinged

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make my bot send a DM to the message author if the message contains the bot's mention in the message, but every time it sends a message, the message author gets a DM, instead of only getting a DM if it contains the bot's mention.

Here's my code.

```js
if (msg.content.includes === '<@!751281320122122311>' || '<@751281320122122311>') {
    msg.author.send({
        embed: {
            color: 3447003,
            title: "Hey",
            description: "Just because I'm a bot, doesn't mean I don't get annoyed when you ping me.",
        }
    });
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: You can simplify your `if` statement with `if (message.mentions.users.has('751281320122122311'))`

Answer (score 3):

I think this should work if you just want to check if the message contains that string or not.

```js
if (
  msg.content.includes("<@!751281320122122311>") ||
  msg.content.includes("<@751281320122122311>")
) {
  msg.author.send({
    embed: {
      color: 3447003,
      title: "Hey",
      description:
        "Just because I'm a bot, doesn't mean I don't get annoyed when you ping me.",
    },
  });
}
```

See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) for more details about the `Array.prototype.includes()` function.

Answer (score 1):

As written, your `if` condition will always be true.

```
if (msg.content.includes === '<@!751281320122122311>' || '<@751281320122122311>') {
```

That says "If `msg.content.includes` equals `'<@!751281320122122311>'`, or if the string value `'<@751281320122122311>'` is truthy, then do this thing." The string literal will always be truthy.

You probably want something more like this:

```
if (msg.content.includes === '<@!751281320122122311>' || msg.content.includes === '<@751281320122122311>') {
```

But even that is probably wrong. `msg.content` is likely a string or an array or something else that has an `includes` function that you mean to be calling. If so, you want this:

```
if (msg.content.includes('<@!751281320122122311>') || msg.content.includes('<@751281320122122311>')) {
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
 if (message.mentions.has(client.user) && !message.mentions.has(message.guild.id)) 
{
    message.author.send({
        embed: {
            color: 3447003,
            title: "Hey",
            description: "Just because I'm a bot, doesn't mean I don't get annoyed when you ping me.",
        }
    });
}
```